# i am trying to installing rolling ridley on Ubuntu 20.04 but getting error :Unable to locate package ros-rolling-desktop

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
i am

```
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
s@V:~$ sudo apt install ros-rolling-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-rolling-desktop
s@V:~$ sudo apt install ros-rolling-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-rolling-ros-base
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357830/i-am-trying-to-installing-rolling-ridley-on-ubuntu-20.04-but-getting-error-:unable-to-locate-package-ros-rolling-desktop/) by [SUDARSAN25](https://answers.ros.org/users/53622/sudarsan25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to not have the GPG keys for packages.ros.org on your system. It looks like you missed a step earlier in the installation process which adds them. If you want more help you need to edit your posts to include more than just the error message. Enough information to fully reproduce the problem will let us do more than guess.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-12**:
Could you please elaborate..
bcoz I did put the gpg keys into source list ..still it shows unable to locate ros rolling

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-09-13**:
@ashin369 Rolling no longer targets 20.04 it now targets 22.04. https://discourse.ros.org/t/rolling-ridley-has-rolled-onto-ubuntu-jammy/24400

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-13**:
I had installed ros2 in ubuntu 22 and i had also ran gpg key installation as per the guide, still I face the same issue.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-09-13**:
Please open a new question with a full description of everything that you did with the commands and the full console outputs. It should not be the same as the above as you're running on a different OS.